# Android Dialog (not custom) problem

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to display a simple alert working on my activity when no internet connection is available, however, for some reason I dont know, when I set the icon for the alert, the box gets messy, too big. Below is my code:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 1:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreen.this)
        .setTitle("Aviso")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
        .setMessage("Acesso à internet não disponível. Clique OK para sair.")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               SplashScreen.this.finish();
           }
        })
        .create();  
    }
    return null;
}
```

the result of this code is displayed in the image below.

[image: device screenshot]

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing anything? This code was straightly copied from the API demos source code, which works perfectly in my device.

Thanks a lot
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the **icon you are using is of large size**....
Scale the image to a **bitmap** upto small size and use **BitmapDrawable**..!! instead of id

Comment: thats weird because the dialog code and the image where copied from the API demo source code, which works fine for me in the emulator and my device as well.

Comment: then your saying that code and image used are also from API demo source..also you saying it works well..but you said "when I set the icon for the alert,the box gets messy" means the image is the prblm...so use smaller image  and check once...

Comment: i changed to the ldpi image from the api demo and it started working. I will keep trying because the image looses its quality because my screen is ldpi. Thanks

Comment: if you use QVGA place image ldpi,...similarly mdpi for HVGA and hdpi for WVGA..then you control the quality of image..

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to change your icon size. If you want to do it programmatically check out this..

```
    // load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
           R.drawable.android);

    int width = bitmapOrg.width();
    int height = bitmapOrg.height();
    int newWidth = 200;
    int newHeight = 200;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // createa matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // rotate the Bitmap
    matrix.postRotate(45);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, 
                      width, height, matrix, true); 

    // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap 
    // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
```

This bitmap can be used as follows

builder.setIcon(bmd);

Answer (score 1):

There is no `width()` and `Height()` functions, below is the corrected the code:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cyj);
int width = bitmapOrg.**getWidth**();
int height = bitmapOrg.**getHeight()**;
int newWidth = 45;
int newHeight = 45;

 // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

// create matrix for the manipulation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// resize the bit map
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

// rotate the Bitmap
matrix.postRotate(0);

// recreate the new Bitmap
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, 
                              width, height, matrix, true); 

// make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap 
// to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
```